# Mobile viewport issues

Tags: mobile, viewport

I am having a few issues with viewport scale on mobile devices. Basically I have set the viewport width as the device width, however it's not scaled to the wrapper div, it's scaled to an inner div, hence some of the outer content is not visible.

Whats more, because it's scaled, it's not possible to zoom out further to see all of the content.

All of the documentation I can find says that viewport device width should just work, any thoughts and suggestions? Link here: [Preview website](http://dempreview.co.uk/staffsmedia/)

I currently have `<meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width">` in the header of all pages but to no avail! Considering going down the route of mobile stylesheets based on the device width.

Comment: is your wrapper div not closed?

Comment: It doesn't appear to be an issue with a missing closing div, W3C validator doesn't show anything related to un-ended divs. Also threw a couple into the footer which made no difference.

Comment: other than that it might be that you need to give that div an id and set the CSS max-width property to 100%. If that does not work post more code